# Drawer menu view requires 2 clicks

Tags: android

A repo with example: https://bitbucket.org/troffel/drawer-button-error

I've come across an issue I can't for the life of me figure out. From a much larger project I was able to deduce it into a smaller dummy project.

Problem:
When the app launches, the buttons in the drawer menu works correctly. However, after changing orientation one or more times the buttons all of a sudden require two key presses.

When logging out events, it shows that the eventlistener connected to the clicked views is triggered, however nothing seem to happen on first click.

I added the main files to the post, repo so you can replicate it if interested.

Any help is much appreciated.

Main layout:

```
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

layout of initial fragment(category_fragment):

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
    <View
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#ecebec"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="openSettings"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"/>  

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment that replaces the initial(preffragment):

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/settings_checkbox_container"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/settings_back"
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Mainactivity:
    package com.example.testdrawer;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.left_drawer, new CategoryFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void openSettings(View v){
        FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ftrans = fmanager.beginTransaction();
        PrefFragment prefFragment = new PrefFragment();
        ftrans.replace(R.id.left_drawer, prefFragment);
        ftrans.commit();
        Log.i("test", "Opening settings");
    }
}
```

categoryfragment code:
    package com.example.testdrawer;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_fragment, container, false);
        //drawer menu
        return v;
    }
}
```

Preffragment.java:
    package com.example.testdrawer;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class PrefFragment extends Fragment{

    private Context context;
    private View checkbox_container;
    private Button settingsBack;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preffragment, container, false);
        checkbox_container = v;
        settingsBack = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.settings_back);
        settingsBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveSettings();
            }
        });

        //setupSimplePreferencesScreen();

        return v;

    }

    public void saveSettings(){
        //setSettings(checkbox_container);

        FragmentManager fmanager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ftrans = fmanager.beginTransaction();
        ftrans.replace(R.id.left_drawer, new CategoryFragment());
        ftrans.commit();

        Log.i("test", "saving settings");
    }
}
```

Comment: I had something similar once when I had set onTouchFocussable in my style.xml. This is too much code to just interpret on the fly though. You might want to consider reformatting it and posting part of your output log.

Comment: if it was onTouchFocussable that was the problem, it wouldn't work on the initial orientation either.

the problem is that this is a condensed as I can do it. My output log doesn't give anything aside from the log statements I have set on the eventlisteners (which confirm that the listener is triggered on both clicks).

Comment: Well, I'm still new to fragments myself but it seems rather strange that you're recreating the fragment every time oncreate is called instead of checking whether one already exists. Maybe it puts both fragments in the same position which then generates 2 calls to the same method? I don't think android actually cares how many things you draw on top of each other, it just checks the location of the widget to see if it was hit. Probably not it but I've encountered weirder things.

Answer (score 0):

OK! This is super weird, but I found the problem.

Using replace(container, fragment) instead of add(container, fragment) in my solved the issue.

The problem was that I was calling add(container, fragment) in my activitys onCreate method. This meant that when an orientation change happened, it would call add(container, fragment) on top of the already existing one.

replace(container, fragment) works because it, logically, replaces the existing one.

A solution that includes using add(container, fragment) would be to have remove(fragment) in my activitys onDestroy method, thus avoiding doable drawing.

Hope it saves someone else some time!